# svn repository: add branches, tags as user

Tags: svn, tags, repository, branch

I started working on a repo with just a trunc dir under the root. According to what i read, it should be possible just to create on the client the missing directories: branches, tags add & commit to the repo and... creating tags and branches should be possible,  right?

Comment: Read the book http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.importing.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`svn mkdir`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.mkdir.html):

`svn mkdir -m "Creating missing /branches and /tags" URL-to-branches URL-to-tags`